# Проблема с расширением в браузере

Tags: python, браузер, расширения

Есть проблема - вот есть к примеру браузер Yandex. Есть сайт - [Вот он](https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/M4A1-S%20%7C%20Nitro%20(Field-Tested)?filter=%22Astralis%20MLG%20Columbus%202016%2C%20Astralis%20MLG%20Columbus%202016%2C%20Astralis%20MLG%20Columbus%202016%22). А вот есть расширение, которое можно включить в браузере - CSGOFloat Market Checker. Воопрос - как мне парсить данные с сайта и данные, которые дает это расширение?

Comment: в selenium не пробовали запускать драйвер с расширением? или подключить к несу ваш профиль, где это расширение установлено (options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Name_Profile\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data'))

Comment: А можно пожалуйста полную команду добавление?